# Python Venv with Windows Linux Subsystem

Tags: windows, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-venv

Just started using Ubuntu on Windows and was impressed with what it could interact with that was Windows things, files and some programs, etc. but I was wondering if anyone has tried or knew more about the possibility of setting up a virtual environment for python that could be used by both windows and the Linux subsystem. Ideally my thought process would be to have the venv that I could install packages to from either a windows pip command or a Linux pip command. Would this work?

Comment: You can run python.exe from Linux.

Comment: Actually this wouldn't work I don't think that linux would be able to run the python.exe...

Update: I did try to link them with an alias but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a 100% solution, but I have found a way to do this with the IDEs that I use. In Jetbrains software you can set up an ssh interpreter. You can set up a localhost ssh in your WSL and use that python environment. This also works with clion.